# Create user in wordpress when payment is completed

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I want to create a user in my wordpress website using a webhook when payment is completed. Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is a function wp_create_user https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/

Comment: This is the article i used to do that [How to automatically register guest users on checkout in WooCommerce](https://usersinsights.com/woocommerce-auto-register-users/).